# Keeping track of multiple threads on iphone

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I'm trying to do something basic to understand threads with a counter that just increments when a button is pressed, and every time the button is pressed, a new thread incrementing the same counter starts.  Then I have a stop button to stop a thread that is running.  How can I tell how many threads, or which thread is running?  Here is my basic template I am working on.  Thanks.

```
-(int)count {
    return count;
}

-(void)setCount:(int) value {
    count = value;
}

-(void)updateDisplay {
    countLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
    count++;
}

-(void)myThread {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDisplay)
                           withObject:nil
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

-(void)startThread {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myThread) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)myThreadStop {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDisplay)
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

-(void)stopThread {
    [self performSelectorInBackground@selector(myThreadStop) withObject:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to keep track of the number of threads you have running, and also assign each thread a unique ID. Assuming that `startThread` is an event handler for your button, you might have something like:

```
static int threadIndex = 0;
static int threadsRunning = 0;

-(void)startThread {
    NSNumber* threadId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:threadIndex++];
    threadsRunning++;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myThread) withObject:threadId];
}
```

Then when you stop a thread, you just decrement `threadsRunning`.

Looking at your code, though, I'm confused by your `stopTread` method, since it seems to be doing the exact same thing as the `myThread` method, i.e., not stopping the thread at all.

Comment: No need with your current setup. The threads you're starting are just going to call `updateDisplay` once and then exit.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing stuff in the background, which is distinct from explicitly creating threads (e.g. it might reuse threads in a thread pool).

If you want *really inefficient* threading code, you could use something like this:

```
NSThread * thread = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myThread) object:nil] autorelease];
[thread start];
while ([thread isExecuting])
{
  NSLog(@"Still running");
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
}
```

**EDIT:** If you're actually going to do iPhone development, I recommend looking at NSOperation/NSInvocationOperation/NSBlockOperation instead. Thread management is a real pain to get right.